# Выполнить команду на удалённом Windows-сервере из-под Linux

Tags: python, linux, windows, shell, windows-server

Есть зоопарк серверов числом более 150. На всех стоят *Windows Server* 2008, 2012, 2012 R2. Машины не в домене, физически находятся по всей стране - от Калининграда до Хабаровска. Настраивались админами на местах, поэтому все прямо очень разные.

Нужна возможность удалённо массово рулить серверами: перезапускать службы, запускать скрипты и тд.

Сейчас есть небольшой сервис на *Flask*, на который ряд необходимых задач обрабатывается (сливается БД, бэкапятся конфиги).

Как в данном контексте (python, сервер на Linux, клиент на Windows Server с разными учётными данными для каждого клиента) удалённо массово выполнять команды аналогично SSH?

Comment: Рекомендую уточнить, а то закроют как общий.

Comment: а собственно где конкретный вопрос или вам посоветывать как mmc с  remote powershell настраивать? Из контекста могу только сказать что вы не в ту сторону смотрите, и вам нужен софт для менеджмента и управления хостами.

Comment: Поправил вопрос на более конкретный

Comment: Вот прям уже 3 месяца как ковыряю `ansible` именно в контексте управления виндовыми бездоменными машинами с win7 и выше. Крайне рекомендую присмотреться. Пока что плохих впечатлений нет. Ну вернее они есть, но касаются только самой винды.

Comment: Присоединяюсь к комментарию от @donRumata - после того как  "пробьётесь" через аутентификацию с Windows, автоматизация с `ansible` - сплошное удовольствие. Советую тщательно ознакомиться с [Ansible Best Practices](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_best_practices.html) - это позволит вам в дальнейшем сэкономить время и не исправлять "детские" ошибки, которые все мы делаем когда только начинаем изучать какой-нибудь продукт.

Comment: net rpc использовать не получится?

Comment: Присоединяюсь к советам посмотреть ансибл. Там же найдете способ, как подключаться к удаленным машинам в домене. У меня правда достаточно критическое восприятие ансибл для того, чтобы ходить на вин машины, но у меня и задачи специфичны.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, сейчас пришёл к тому, что под данную задачу подходит SaltStack.

Установка на клиентах элементарна, взаимодействует с сервером на "ура", в отличие от ансибла, который, хоть я и люблю до ужаса, но с зоопарком машин дружит так себе.

Единственный минус - всё несколько менее логично, чем в ансибле, но тоже очень круто и приятно